# Windows displays a black screen instead of password prompt

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

I was trying to setup a second display with my laptop, but the second display wasn't connecting. I set them up as 'extend monitor' and clicked Ok. The monitor of my laptop froze, displaying only the wallpaper and nothing else. The secondary monitor kept on being non-responsive (but I suspect a bad cable).

As much as I tried to revert the changes, my laptop wouldn't take any command and the cursor disappeared. I shut it down to perform a restart. Everything went normal until the time came to enter my password. The screen remains black and I cannot do anything.

I can access safe mode and use it normally, but I can no longer do a normal start.

I am using windows 7. The laptop has never had similar problems.

I tried alt+ctrl+del to no use. The display settings in safe mode are normal. The secondary monitor is disconnected.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bad cable/adapter. Are you going through a docking station or plugging your monitor in directly to your laptop? What kind of video cable are you using? If you can see your background on your laptop you should also be able to move your mouse to it - you can either blindly try to grab your Display settings window and drag it to your laptop or you can just unplug your monitor and try a new cable. Make sure your cable isn't visibly damaged (pins included) and that everything is plugged in snug, and sometimes restarting will help wake your monitor/video settings up.

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with the projector button on your laptop if you have one.  Press it once then wait about 5 seconds to see if this corrects the issue - this button will swap "modes" between duplicate, extend, and disabled when its working correctly.  Its possible your laptop is stuck in extended mode, with the alternate monitor set as the primary.

[image: Projector Button]

Comment: It may take a few tries to get the monitor extension settings to swap back to "disabled"

Comment: I suspected the same, about the laptop getting stuck in duplicate mode with the external monitor set as primary. However this method isn't taking me anywhere so far. I am going to try it again later, thanks for the reply.